# How to upload assets when creating a CloudFormation stack using the CreateChangeSet API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I am trying to create and deploy a new AWS CloudFormation stack via the SDK's API (in TypeScript but the language is not relevant here).

I am using the [CreateChangeSet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_CreateChangeSet.html) call which takes a JSON CloudFormation template as parameter and will create the corresponding stack:

```
const changeSet = await cfClient.send(new CreateChangeSetCommand({
    StackName: stackName,
    ChangeSetName: changeSetName,
    ChangeSetType: 'CREATE',
    TemplateBody: '<MY JSON TEMPLATE HERE>',
}));

await cfClient.send(new ExecuteChangeSetCommand({ StackName: stackName, ChangeSetName: changeSetName }));
```

This has been working fine for a while with simple stacks, but I am now reaching a point where I need to deploy assets alongside the JSON template (for example the code of an AWS Lambda).

What would be taken care of for me by the AWS CLI in a normal situation would be that `cdk deploy` would first upload the assets to S3 and then deploy the stack, and pass a set of parameters telling CloudFormation where to find the assets in S3.

However, the CreateChangeSet API call does not deal with the assets and will only upload the JSON template, which leads to the following error, complaining that the parameters for the assets don't have a value:

```
Parameters: [RandomParamForAsset1, RandomParamForAsset2, RandomParamForAsset3] must have values
```

Therefore, I would like to know if there is an API call that takes care of also deploying the assets before deploying the changeset in CloudFormation?

If it helps, I have access to the CloudAssembly at runtime, it's where I get the JSON template from:

```
const app = new App({ outdir: templateDir });
new MySuperAwesomeStack(app, 'SuperAwesomeStack', {
  ...someProps
});
let cloudAssembly: CloudAssembly = app.synth();
```

Thanks

Comment: You can try using [`cdk-assets`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cdk-assets) to upload the assets for you. You can view its source code to see how it uploads. It's just a JSON file. Also, why not just use `cdk`?

Comment: Unfortunately it seems like the CDK API calls we use do not generate the required `assets.json` file needed, I had already looked into that option. I can't use the cdk CLI.

Answer (score 0):

If youre using CDK, it can do this for you mostly automatically, using AssetCode for example for lambdas.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-lambda.AssetCode.html

Using that construct combined with `cdk deploy` will automatically zip your lambda's up and push them to an s3 bucket for deployment.

Note however, `cdk deploy` does everything. You mention something about using Changeset and having cdk deploy just put the assets into the cloud? Thats not needed. `cdk deploy` will zip, push to s3, create the template, create the change set, push change set with proper links to the right s3 zip objects, and execute.

Otherwise, you'll have to do it manually. There is no one magic aws cli command that does all of it for you.

You need to zip up each asset, then put those assets in an s3 bucket, then tell the cloudformation template where those s3 buckets are in order for it to grab the asset zips from there to use in deployment.

Comment: I am using the API to deploy my change sets, not the CLI, this is inapplicable in this case.

Comment: the cli *is* the Api. I do not understand what you mean by the difference.  Everything interacting with AWS is done through the AWS SDK API - all of the SDKs in various languages and CDK all interact through the same set of commands that are distilled into the CLI. The aws console even still uses these values. Please elaborate as to what you are trying to do then

Comment: The CLI does more than just perform an API call, it will bundle the assets, upload them to S3, create the change set and deploy it all in a single command for you. I need the asset bundling and upload part but done without going through the CLI (because our service deploys new stacks at runtime on demand). Anyway, I did end up managing to upload all the assets by hand but it turned out to be useless as they are not compiled (quite obviously) when the CloudAssembly is generated, just taken as-is.